# doctrine 2.1: memory usage increased after flush

Tags: php, memory-management, orm, memory-leaks, doctrine

it is really unintuitive to me why after flush() the memory get increased instead of decreased? I cannot find anything useful in the documentation. I am flushing every 50 loop iterations and after each flush memory usage is being increased by 1MB. 100 flushing uses 100MB ! What am I missing here? I have seen on doctrine's website example with clear(), but it  if I use it I got an exception that one of my object does not have cascade persist set. Could anyone explain me what is done behind the scenes and what should I do to properly unset all doctrine's objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that the entity manager handles all objects. You should reset it if you dont need the objects in ram after each X iterations. Try this out:

```
// get the entity manager and save objects and flush
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
...
$em->flush();

// then reset the entity manager
$this->get('doctrine')->resetEntityManager();
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, read here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html

It suggests to use $em->clear() after every bulk of operations. (which should give the same effect as Besnik suggested).

From the previously mentioned link:

> Bulk inserts in Doctrine are best performed in batches, taking
>   advantage of the transactional write-behind behavior of an
>   EntityManager. The following code shows an example for inserting 10000
>   objects with a batch size of 20. You may need to experiment with the
>   batch size to find the size that works best for you. Larger batch
>   sizes mean more prepared statement reuse internally but also mean more
>   work during flush.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with bulk inserting records (over 100K). I followed Rauni and Besnik suggestions and Doctrine's guide to batching but the memory still grew even after $em->clear() and resetEntityManager(). After a few days, I headed the information notice on Doctrine's documentation:

> An ORM tool is not primarily well-suited for mass inserts, updates or
>   deletions. Every RDBMS has its own, most effective way of dealing with
>   such operations and if the options outlined below are not sufficient
>   for your purposes we recommend you use the tools for your particular
>   RDBMS for these bulk operations.

and used raw SQL (MySQL) and batched the inserts. Memory usage went from over 200MB with Doctrine down to 30MB with raw SQL. And I could see the memory usage decrease as I popped the elements to be inserted off of the source array. Also much quicker, from 220 seconds to 20 seconds.